# Jsr 303 validation on list and list elements

Tags: bean-validation

I am struggling with defining my jsr 303 validation rules, namely redefining default group for my container bean.

```
@GroupSequence({Container.class, Container.Step2.class})
public class Container {
@NotNull
private String def;

@Valid
@Size(min = 20, groups = Container.Step2.class)
private List<Element> elems = new LinkedList<Element>();

public interface Step2{}
}

public class Element{
@NotNull
private String foo;
}
```

I would like to have Size of container bean validated if and only if:

- def property is valid
- no validation errors of any of Elements beans  withing elems collection

If i validate Container with default group:

```
Container c = new Container();
...
validator.validate(c)
```

size validator is fired even if there are validation errors for inner element bean.

If i remove @GroupSequence from container class (skip redefining default group for Container) and define own GroupSequence as:

```
@GroupSequence({Default.class, Container2.Step2.class}) 
public interface AllValid{}
```

then validation with AllValid group:

```
Container c = new Container();
...
validator.validate(c, Container2.AllValid.class);
```

everything works as expected.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to take a look into source code of hibernate-validator to investigate the problem. It looks as cascading validation of associations is performed after validation of root bean. Both validations (validation of root bean and associations) are performed with "target group". By "target group" i mean group you pass as a last argument to validate method. In case no group/groups parameters are passed, the "default group" is set as "target group". In my case I redefined default group for root bean so  call to:

```
validator.validate(c)
```

forces Container bean to be validated with group sequence:Default,Container.Step2.class. Just after that list of elems is validated (with default group). In this case Container and elems are independently validated.

If some knows any trick to make my validation work with default group please comment my post but for now i will stay with validation of Container with explicit group, i.e.

```
validator.validate(c, Container2.AllValid.class);
```